# Como puedo crear un buscador en un archivo python?

Tags: python

mi problema es el siguiente, estoy estudiando python y estamos haciendo una pequeña lista de contactos, la cual guarda todos los registros de datos en un archivo .csv, el profesor nos pidio que hicieramos un buscador para buscar y mostrar contactos especificos, que al poner el nombre de un contacto la consola devuelva el nombre, apellido y numero del contacto, llevo un par de dias intentando y leyendo pero no he encontrado la respuesta, queria saber si alguien podia darme una mano, adjunto el codigo del prtograma

````
    nombre = input("Ingresa el nombre del contacto ")
    apellido = input("ingrese el apellido ")
    celular = input("Ingresa el celular ")
    datos = nombre.title() + ";" + apellido.title() + ";" + celular + ";" + "\n"
    archivo = open("agenda.csv", "a")
    archivo.write(datos)
    archivo.close()

def mostrar():
    import os
    if(os.path.exists("./agenda.csv")):
        archivo = open("agenda.csv", "r")
        for linea in archivo:
            campos = linea.split(";")
            print("{} {} {}".format(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2]))
        archivo.close()
    else:
        print("El archivo no existe")

def menu():
    opcion = ""
    while (opcion != "s"):
        print ("a) agregar contacto")
        print ("b) Mostrar contactos")
        print ("c) Buscar contactos")
        print ("s) salir")

        opcion = input("Que opcion deseas seleccionar? ")

        if (opcion == "a"):
            escribir()
        elif (opcion == "b"):
            mostrar()
        elif (opcion == "s"):
            break
        elif (opcion == "c"):
            buscar()
        else:
            print("{} Opcion no valida".format(opcion))
menu() ```


solo faltaria definir la funcion de busqueda, el resto de funciones corren correctamente, pero llevo 2 dias con un amigo rompiendonos la cabeza averiguando como crear el maldito buscador, si alguien puede decirme como y adjuntar una explicacion estaria muy agradecido.
````

Comment: Hola Franco, bienvenido, te estás ahogando en un vaso de agua, a tu función **mostrar** la modificas para que reciba un parámetro (la cadena a buscar), le agregas un **if** que detecte coincidencias, un return y boileau!!

Comment: podrias explicarme como hacerlo? ya lo he intentado pero me devuelve un error de que el dato ingresado no esta en la lista

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta tu función **buscar** para saber que cambiar.

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un buscador en Python para su lista de contactos, podría utilizar el módulo CSV de Python para leer el archivo "agenda.csv" en una lista de diccionarios. Luego, puede solicitar al usuario que ingrese el nombre de un contacto y buscar en la lista de diccionarios si existe un contacto con el mismo nombre. Si se encuentra un contacto, se puede imprimir su nombre, apellido y número de teléfono.

```
import csv

def buscar(nombre):
    with open("agenda.csv", "r") as archivo:
        lector = csv.DictReader(archivo, delimiter=';')
        encontrado = False
        for contacto in lector:
            if contacto["nombre"] == nombre:
                encontrado = True
                print(f"Nombre: {contacto['nombre']}\nApellido: {contacto['apellido']}\nCelular: {contacto['celular']}")
        if not encontrado:
            print(f"No se encontró ningún contacto con el nombre '{nombre}'")

def menu():
    opcion = ""
    while opcion != "s":
        print("a) Agregar contacto")
        print("b) Mostrar contactos")
        print("c) Buscar contactos")
        print("s) Salir")

        opcion = input("Que opción deseas seleccionar? ")

        if opcion == "a":
            escribir()
        elif opcion == "b":
            mostrar()
        elif opcion == "c":
            nombre = input("Ingresa el nombre del contacto que quieres buscar: ")
            buscar(nombre)
        elif opcion == "s":
            break

def escribir():
    nombre = input("Ingresa el nombre del contacto: ")
    apellido = input("Ingresa el apellido del contacto: ")
    celular = input("Ingresa el número de celular del contacto: ")
    with open("agenda.csv", "a") as archivo:
        escritor = csv.writer(archivo, delimiter=';')
        escritor.writerow([nombre.title(), apellido.title(), celular])

def mostrar():
    with open("agenda.csv", "r") as archivo:
        lector = csv.reader(archivo, delimiter=';')
        for campos in lector:
            print("{} {} {}".format(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2]))

menu()
```

En el código anterior agregué una nueva opción "c" en el menú para buscar contactos. La función "buscar" toma el nombre de un contacto como entrada y busca el archivo CSV para cualquier contacto que tenga ese nombre. Si se encuentra un contacto, imprime su nombre, apellido y número de teléfono. Si no se encuentra ningún contacto con el nombre proporcionado, se imprime un mensaje indicando que no se encontró ningún contacto.

Nota: Asegúrate de que los encabezados de columna en el archivo CSV estén en minúsculas y sin espacios para que el código funcione correctamente. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```
def mostrar( textoBuscado, tipo ):
    import os
    if( os.path.exists( "./agenda.csv" )):
        archivo = open( "agenda.csv", "r" )
        noHay = True
        lista = archivo.split( "\n" )
        for usuario in lista:
            campos = usuario.split( ";" )
            if( textoBuscado == campos[ tipo ] ):
                print("{} {} {}".format(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2]))
                noHay = False

        if( noHay ):
            print( "No se han encontrado coincidencias" ) 
        archivo.close()

    else:
        print("El archivo no existe")
```

Como podés ver, las modificaciones son mínimas, antes del for agregué un booleano que uso para saber si tengo que imprimir el mensaje de "no encontrado", después creé un array separando por filas el archivo guardado.
En el for creo otro array separando el contenido de cada fila con ";", luego, mediante un if, comparo el texto buscado con el valor contenido en el array en la posición "tipo", si hay coincidencia se imprimen los datos encontrados y se le asigna a "noHay" False, para no mostrar el mensaje de "no encontrado".
PD: el tipo te sirve para buscar bien por nombre, por apellido o por celular y si no te interesa lo podés quitar.
Espero haberlo explicado bien.